# Java is printing out char array length as 0 even though I have assigned it a length

Tags: java, arrays, getter-setter, encapsulation

I am a beginner in Java and I've been stuck on this for three days. I have two classes. Class called Main has the main method and asks for user input and class called DoThings does things with the user input.

I want the main class to ask the user for a number. The doThings class will take this number, multiply it by 4 and set it as the length of a 1D array. Then print the length of the array.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        //Create object called Exercise to perform the task
        DoThings Exercise = new DoThings();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        //Ask user for a number
        System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
        
        //Number is passed to the setNumber setter method in DoThings class
        Exercise.setNumber(scanner.nextInt());
        
        //Getter method is used to pass number to the setMultiplyFour setter method in DoThings class
        Exercise.setMultiplyFour(Exercise.getNumber());
           
           //Print out the length of the array
           System.out.println(Exercise.array.length);         
    }
}
```

This is the second class.

```
public class DoThings {

    private int number;
    private int multiplyFour;
    //Created array with the length as multiplyFour
    char[] array = new char[this.multiplyFour];

    //Setters
    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    public void setMultiplyFour(int number) {
        this.multiplyFour = number * 4;
    }
    
    //Getters
    public int getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }
    public int getMultiplyFour() {
        return this.multiplyFour;
    }   
}
```

But when I print the result, it's coming as 0? Why is this?
Thank you!!

Comment: Calling `setMultiplyFour()` does not re-evaluate the `new char[this.multiplyFour]` expression of the `array` initialization. That is evaluated when you call `new DoThings()`, and `multiplyFour` has value 0 at that time.

Comment: Java primitive arrays are of fixed size once initialized, their size doesn't get changed unless reference variable (.array) here has been modified to point at different array now which is of different size. So as @Andreas said, the array was already initialized with capacity of `0`

Answer (score 2):

When `char[] array = new char[this.multiplyFour];` this code is executed, the value of `this.multiplyFour` is 0 (ints have a default value of 0 in Java). When you update `this.multiplyFour`, its value change but the array doesn't magically gets re-allocated. You have to re-allocate your array manually, when you update `this.multiplyFour`.

```
public void setMultiplyFour(int number) {
    this.multiplyFour = number * 4;
    this.array = new char[this.multiplyFour];
}
```

Comment: I see...so just to understand what I did wrong. I created the `private int multiplyFour;` variable. Its default value is 0. Then I created a method to set multiplyFour to a different variable. But because I created the array before updating `multiplyFour`, the length of the array got set to 0?

Comment: @SanjanaSenthil Yes.

Comment: Thank you!! Can't believe it took me three days to figure out something which is actually quite simple

Comment: @SanjanaSenthil You are welcome, you are still learning. Good luck with your future endeavors.